# Can removable discontinuities be ignored while integrating?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, continuity

A function needs to be continuous in order to be integrable.

However,  can single point removable discontinuities be ignored while integrating? I ask this because obviously a point isn't going to add anything to the *area* of the graph which is what integration returns. Is it also the case with improper integrals of discontinuous functions. I feel it shouldn't be valid for them because "too many points" finally might end up resulting in a considerable area.

Edit: Referring to Reimann Integrability.

Comment: Continuity is not required for Riemann integrability anyway. But yes, removable discontinuities in particular are not a problem.

Comment: For a more general answer, you will need to clarify which specific type of integration you are referring to (*Riemann, Lebesgue, Darboux, ...*).  For Lebesgue integration, for instance, any null-set can be ignored however what constitutes a null-set varies based on context.  Using the usual measure, any countable set (*including countably infinite sets*) can be ignored.  For example $\int_{[0,1]}f(x)d\mu=1$ using the usual Lebesgue measure and $f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}~x\in\Bbb Q\\ 1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$